# Firmware in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

In the home directory of Linux kernel source tree, there is a directory "firmware". The files in the directory ends with .ihex.

When request_firmware is called, as per http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-14-sect-8,

> The proper solution is to obtain the firmware from user space when you
>   need it

So I suppose the firmware is loaded from /lib/firmware (not sure googled it).
So what are those .ihex files doing there? What are they for?

Thanks

Comment: Because it's a kernel source. Sometimes firmware is loaded to the device by a driver. And sometimes firmware is shipped by the device manufacturer as a binary file as it is intellectual property. So i assume that those binary files are copied to /lib/firmware at the driver compile time. In other words binary firmware is a part of kernel source.

Comment: I checked.. they are not copied. contents are different (even file sizes)

Comment: .ihex is for Intel HEX format, a method for storing a binary image as printable  ASCII characters, that dates back to the 1960s.  The `Makefile`, `README.AddingFirmware`, and `WHENCE` files in the Linux firmware/ directory has most of the answers to your questions.  *"contents are different (even file sizes)"* -- Are you comparing apples to oranges (Intel HEX to binary)?

Comment: Thanks @sawdust. Didnt know they were apples and oranges.. They were just fruits for me :p Now they taste different. Thanks again